# An error while pushing

Tags: git, mercurial, push, git-remote

I tried to push to a mercurial repo with

```
~/pychess$ git push i175 branches/i175loc
searching for changes
no changes found
error: src refspec branches/i175loc does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'hg::https://G.nius.ck@code.google.com/r/gniusck-pychess175/'
```

It doesn't even ask for my credentials. I am using Git 2.1.0 and the newest (at the time of this post) version of git remote hg.

Comment: Why are you pushing a mercurial repo with git? shouldn't you be using `hg` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried git remote hg. However, your command seems wrong: you should try

```
git push i175 i175loc
```

ie: do not prefix the name of the branch by `branches/`